# PHP - How to store a resource for later use

Tags: php

I would like to store the resources from proc_exe for later use. This way I can communicate with the open process... But it seems that it cannot be stored in $_SESSION, does anyone have any idea how to store it?

```
 session_start();
if(is_resource($_SESSION['process']))
{
  echo "I was here";
  proc_close($_SESSION['process']);
}
else
{
  $descriptorspec = array(
     0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
     1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
     2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
  );
  $_SESSION['process'] = proc_open("myProgram", $descriptorspec, $p, null, null);
  if(is_resource($_SESSION['process']))
  {
    echo "<pre>";
      print_r($_SESSION); //Untill here everything of
    echo "</pre>";
  }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Resources can't be saved, they're specific to the current PHP process.

Comment: Is there any way of starting a process and then "talk" to it while I want? Thanks

Comment: Look into websockets.

Comment: and with ssh2 functions it is not possible either?

Comment: No. You can only save plain data: numbers, strings, array, objects. Nothing that refers to external resources like network connections, processes, file handles.